# MVVM and window lists

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm writing an app that lets users browse through data, and I want to use the FireFox UI style: allow the user to open as many windows as they want, each with as many tabs as they want. I also want to try to do this using the Model-View-ViewModel pattern as much as possible.

Opening a new tab should be easy enough to handle in MVVM. Make an ObservableCollection of TabViewModel, bind that collection to the ItemsSource of a TabControl, and then opening a new tab is theoretically as easy as adding a new TabViewModel to the collection.

Here's the question that interests me: Is there a way to do the same thing for opening a new *window*? I.e., databind an ObservableCollection of WindowViewModel to the ItemsSource of... the Application's Windows collection?... so that when I add a new WindowViewModel to the observable collection, a new window automatically opens? And then tie that into app startup, so that instead of setting StartupUri, I just add the first WindowViewModel to the collection?

Since I can't actually databind Application.Windows, what would be the best way for the ViewModel layer to:

1. Add a new WindowViewModel and have a new Window appear automatically;
2. Remove the WindowViewModel and have its Window automatically close.
3. Remove the WindowViewModel from the collection if the user closes the window.

I could write my own object that watches an INotifyCollectionChanged and opens/closes windows in response to collection events, but I'm not sure whether that's the best way -- and if it is, I'm not sure of the best way to hook it into the application. Anyone have thoughts on the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of MVVM is, that the ViewModel **doesn't** have to concern itself (in detail) with **how** the View will react to changes in the ViewModel.

One possibility would be a simple tracking algorithm in the View listening to the CollectionChanged event in the ViewModel, creating and destroying Windows on the go:

```
Dictionary<WindowModel, WindowView> _cache = new;
void WindowModelListChangedHandler(sender, args) {
    switch(args.Action) {
        case Add:
            _cache[args.NewItem] = new WindowView(args.NewItem);
            _cache[args.NewItem].Show();
            break;
        case Remove:
            // ...
    }    
}
```